# ping working but wget (apache) doesn't

Tags: networking

Currently, all the pcs at the office are in a domain although the server seems to be down: Sometimes I have to disconnect the pc to be able to login. Anyway, I set up a local testing server (centos), connected it, and added a rule in the DHCP server. We are able to access its apache server on port 80 using the ip address as host.

Now, I want to setup an apache server on my windows machine. It is setup and accessible from localhost only. Other pcs including the linux server can ping my machine but can not actually access `http://my_id`. I am a bit knowledgeable with apache configuration so it is not an issue. I tried adding rules to the firewall to allow incoming port 80 tcp connections (and also upd just in case). The problem persisted and still did even when I turned off the firewall.

I am thinking I should remove my pc from the active directory (domain). I am not really sure why would the centos server be accessible and mine not if not because of the setup: It definitely has nothing to do with the static entry in the DHCP conf especially that ping works. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What's Apache looking at? 127.0.0.1? Do you have any desktop "security solution" installed?

Comment: Telnet from other PC  to your IP and port 80 to see if connection gets through.